# How does Google Analytics calculate the number of visitors

Tags: google-analytics

If I visit a site 100 times a day (from one IP) does Google Analytics track that as 100 unique visitors?

Comment: If you delete the cookies that uniquely identify you, maybe.

Answer (score 6):

According to this article, visitor uniqueness is determined by using cookies rather than other identifying factors (such as IP address, browser identification string, etc.): https://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33087. This means that you will be counted as a single visitor as long as you do not delete your GA cookies -- and even if you change IP addresses while browsing.

Comment: And don't use a different browser, since cookies are not shared between browsers.

Answer (score 5):

No. Google uses a cookie to track visitors so that counts as one. [This video](http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/interpreting_reports_visits/index.html) explains in detail: